# show/hide dropdown items based on previous dropdown selection

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

**- - edited as i described it incorrectly first time round, sorry! - -**

Hi,

i am trying to use show/hide to manipulate what is shown in a second dropdown menu, based on what is selected in the first dropdown menu. However after having it work briefly, it now doesn't across any browser, it just shows them all no matter what is selected. **When an option is selected in the first menu, it needs to then display particular options in the second menu.** Each airport has it's own set of destinations. Unfortunately there isn't a php/mysql database option for this :/

the js is as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#from_BLANK").click(function () {
        $("#to_A1").show();
        $("#to_A2").show();
        $("#to_A3").show();
    });
    $("#from_A1").click(function () {
        $("#to_A1").hide();
        $("#to_A2").show();
        $("#to_A3").show();
    });
    $("#from_A2").click(function () {
        $("#to_A1").show();
        $("#to_A2").hide();
        $("#to_A3").show();
    });
    $("#from_A3").click(function () {
        $("#to_A1").show();
        $("#to_A2").show();
        $("#to_A3").hide();
    });
});
```

And the html on the dropdowns is as follows:

```
<select name="depApt" id="depApt">
    <option id="from_BLANK" selected="selected">&nbsp;</option>
    <option id="from_A1" value="A1">Airport One</option>
    <option id="from_A2" value="A2">Airport Two</option>
    <option id="from_A3" value="A3">Airport Three</option>
</select>

<select name="dstApt" id="dstApt">
    <option id="to_BLANK" selected="selected">&nbsp;</option>
    <option id="to_A1" value="A1">Airport One</option>
    <option id="to_A2" value="A2">Airport Two</option>
    <option id="to_A3" value="A3">Airport Three</option>
</select>
```

Are there any glaring errors? or maybe better ways to achieve this?

Any and all help most appreciated!

cheers,
Paul

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the script which will prevent both dropdown from being the same other than both are blank. The option in B will always be disabled if the corresponding one in A is selected.

Tested in IE8 and FF3.5 and Chrome.

Javascript:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" >
    $(function() {
    $('#depApt').click(function(){
        var idx = $(this).attr("selectedIndex") + 1;
        $('#dstApt option').removeAttr('disabled');
        if($('#dstApt').attr("selectedIndex") == idx - 1)
          $('#dstApt').attr("selectedIndex", 0)
        $('#dstApt option:nth-child(' + idx + ')').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
      }
    );
    });
  </script>
```

HTML:

```
<select name="depApt" id="depApt">
  <option>&nbsp;</option>
  <option value="A1">Airport One</option>
  <option value="A2">Airport Two</option>
  <option value="A3">Airport Three</option>
</select>

<select name="dstApt" id="dstApt">
  <option>&nbsp;</option>
  <option value="A1">Airport One</option>
  <option value="A2">Airport Two</option>
  <option value="A3">Airport Three</option>
</select>
```

PS: I've removed all the IDs of the options as they are not required for my codes, restore it back if needed.

Comment: that worked perfectly! Although it has now highlighted my error in the description :(

it's not that i need to just hide the option, but selecting an airport in the first box needs to then display particular options in the second box! Good way to stuff up my first post on here :(

Comment: Hiding the option will not work on all browsers, disabling them will. As for you actual full requirements, my method will only work if you place all the possible options inside and then use your own rules to disable/enable them. One thing for sure, you can fly from and to the same place. :)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this answer I gave to a similar question:

> [Removing and adding options from a group of select menus with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2008287/removing-and-adding-options-from-a-group-of-select-menus-with-jquery/2008350#2008350)

It should work perfectly for you, and I've also supplied an link to a working example at the end.

Comment: Thank you :) will that still work when the option values are just text and not integers? I can't do a val > 0 as you have on there :/

Comment: @Paul S, yes, the method will work, you just have to tune the logic a bit. Instead of `val > 0`, you can use `val != 'to_BLANK'`.